# How to partially mock external object

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, bdd, ocmock

I have class method to test with dependant object (Keys object)

*APIRouter.m*

```
+ (NSURL*)apiURLWithPath:(NSString*)path {
    MyKeys *keys = [MyKeys new];
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?api_key=%@", path, [keys APIKey]];
    return [NSURL URLWithString:url];
}
```

I am trying to partially mock this Keys object and return "MY_API_KEY" value but the test method fails and returns real API key (e.g. as78d687as6d7das8da).

*APIRouterSpec.m*

```
describe(@"APIRouter", ^{
    it(@"should return url for api", ^{
        Keys *keys = [Keys new];
        id keysPartialMock = OCMPartialMock(keys);
        OCMStub([keysPartialMock APIKey]).andReturn(@"MY_API_KEY");
        NSURL *url = [APIRouter apiURLWithPath:@"http://www.api.com/v1/events"];
        expect([url absoluteString]).to.equal([NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.api.com/v1/events?api_key=MY_API_KEY"]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you:

Somewhere outside your test method:

```
static NSString *gMockApiKey = @"MY_API_KEY";
```

Stub the method like this:

```
OCMStub([keysPartialMock APIKey]).andDo(^(NSInvocation *invocation)
{
    [invocation setReturnValue:&gMockApiKey];
});
```

**Edit:**

Since APIRouter is probably using its own instance of Keys you can try a class mock:

```
id keysMock = OCMClassMock([Keys class]);
OCMStub(ClassMethod([keysMock APIKey])).andDo(^(NSInvocation *invocation)
{
    [invocation setReturnValue:&gMockApiKey];
});
```

**Edit2:**

So.. I think the proper way to mock it would be to create a mock instance of Keys.

Somewhere at the top of your test file:

```
static Keys *gMockedKeys = nil;
static NSString *gMockApiKey = @"MY_API_KEY";
```

setUp:

```
- (void)setUp {

    [super setUp];

    gMockedKeys = [Keys new];

    id keysPartialMock = OCMPartialMock(gMockedKeys);
    OCMStub([keysPartialMock APIKey]).andDo(^(NSInvocation *invocation)
    {
        [invocation setReturnValue:&gMockApiKey];
    });
}
```

test:

```
- (void)testAPIURLWithPath {

    id keysMock = OCMClassMock([Keys class]);
    OCMStub([keysMock new]).andReturn(gMockedKeys);

    NSURL *url = [APIRouter apiURLWithPath:@"http://www.api.com/v1/events"];
    NSString *expectedUrlString = [url absoluteString];
    XCTAssertEqualObjects(expectedUrlString, @"http://www.api.com/v1/events?api_key=MY_API_KEY", @"It Should work now..");
}
```

Comment: Right, I think I know why. We're trying a partial mock of an instance of Keys and APIRouter (i'm assuming) is using its own instance. You can try a class mock of Keys. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I tried it as well but it still doesnt work :) `APIKey` is an instance method of `Keys` class. There is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/tailec/17a614fc602d09f13d2a) to more detailed code with interfaces etc.

Comment: @tailec I updated my answer yet again... It should work now, but you might want to do some refactoring and cleanups.

Comment: It works, great! Thank you. I am learning OCMock and this example looks pretty complex for achieving simple thing.

Comment: @tailec it might look complex at first but I think that's the way to go. You can use this concept for more complex cases. You're actually "injecting" a mock class to be used by the other class that you're testing. Though I'm not sure if it's right to use globals, maybe they can be members of the test class. Anyway, I'm glad that it worked out :)